# How to count all substrings in a string, and then sort based on if they begin with a vowel

Tags: python, substring

I tried doing it like this:

```
# the system waits for the user's string input
word = input() 

# defining vowels
vowels = "aeiou"

#// BEGIN_TODO [count_substrings] counting all substrings in a string
count_c: int = 0
count_v: int = 0
total_substrings = (len(word)*(len(word)+1)) // 2
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        for i in range(total_substrings):
            for j in range(i, total_substrings):
                count_v += 1
    if letter not in vowels:
        for i in range(total_substrings):
            for j in range(i, total_substrings):
                count_c += 1
print('number of substrings starting with Vowels: {} - number of substrings starting with Consonants: {}'.format(count_v, count_c))
#// END_TODO [count_substrings]
```

but the code outputs strange numbers. Help would be appreciated on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do the same thing twice: You use a formula to *calculate* the number of substrings, but then you also try to *count* them with loops. One of those is unnecessary. Or you could combine a little calculation and a little counting like this:

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"
word = 'test'

n = len(word)
count_v: int = 0
count_c: int = 0

for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    # number of substrings starting at i, not counting the empty string:
    n_substrings = n - i
    if letter in VOWELS:
        count_v += n_substrings
    else:
        count_c += n_substrings
        
print(f"number of substrings starting with vowels: {count_v}")
print(f"number of substrings starting with consonants: {count_c}")
```

```
number of substrings starting with vowels: 3
number of substrings starting with consonants: 7
```

Note, however, that this approach will overcount if there are identical substrings that can be started at different points in the string. For example, if `word = 'eel'`, the substring `'e'` would be counted twice. If you don't want that, it gets more complicated. You could extract all the substrings and collect them in two sets (one for those starting with a vowel, and one for the rest), to remove the duplicates.